# How to get the following sibling in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am fairly new to XSLT and this is my XML:

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <number>1</number>
        <title>Project X</title>
    </project>
    <project>
        <number>2</number>
        <title>Project Y</title>
    </project>
    <project>
        <number>3</number>
        <title>Project Z</title>
    </project>
</projects>
```

If I have one project and want to get the sibling that follows it, how can I do that?

This code doesn't seem to work for me:

```
/projects[title="Project X"]/following-sibling
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is actually a completely XPath question.

**Use**:

```
/*/project[title = 'Project X']/following-sibling::project[1]
```

This selects any first following sibling `Project` of any `Project` element that is a child of the top element in the XML document and the string value of at least of one of its `title` children is the string `"Project X"`.

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/*/project[title = 'Project X']/following-sibling::project[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <number>1</number>
        <title>Project X</title>
    </project>
    <project>
        <number>2</number>
        <title>Project Y</title>
    </project>
    <project>
        <number>3</number>
        <title>Project Z</title>
    </project>
</projects>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the correctly-selected element is copied to the output:**

```
<project>
   <number>2</number>
   <title>Project Y</title>
</project>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work within a `xsl:for-each` loop. How could this work in a loop?

Comment: @basZero, please, be precise when saying "this" and "doesn't work". Without seeing your code and a definition of what must be achieved, it is unrealistic to expect that anyone would be able to understand the comment and provide a helpful reply. I would recommend that you ask a separate, new SO question, properly formatting the XML document and the XSLT code, defining the wanted result and providing the actual result. Let's avoid guessing and save everybody's time.