# Removing next element following an XSL match

Tags: xslt

```
<remark role="removethis"/>
<para>Content to be removed.</para>
<para>Don't remove this.</para>
```

---

I want to remove the element directly after a remark that has the role="removethis".
In the above example,

```
<para>Content to be removed.</para>
```

will be removed.
The element to be removed does not have to be a para. It can be a screen, programlisting etc.

I thought using following-sibling might do this (see below). But that matches all following siblings.

```
 <xsl:template match="remark[@role = 'removethis']::following-sibling"/>
```

Comment: "*I thought using following-sibling might do this (see below). But that matches all following siblings.*" No, it produces an error.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246371/how-to-get-the-following-sibling-in-xslt

Comment: <xsl:template match="remark[@role = 'removethis']/following-sibling::*[1]"/>

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. `remark[@role = 'removethis']::following-sibling` is not a valid XPath expression;
2. You cannot use the `following-sibling` axis in a *location step* of a [match pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#patterns). Any axes other than `child` or `attribute` can only be used in *predicates*.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="para[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::remark[@role='removethis']]]"/>
```

---

There's probably a simpler way to solve this, but you're only showing us a partial picture.

Comment: The matched element may not always be a para.

Comment: @mikey So replace `para` with `*`. Or (preferably) with a list of elements that may appear in that position.

Comment: So this means: match first element of any type, where preceding sibling is a remark role="removethis". I don't follow how the self clause is used.
Excuse me, as I never normally need to construct such a complex match expression. This is advanced stuff for me.

Comment: If you replace `para` with `*` then it means match **any** element whose **immediately** preceding sibling is a `remark` whose `role` attribute equals to the string "removethis".