XSLT - How to loop through each entry, but print out one line
First I have to say, that I'm no expert in XML/XSLT transforming. So please be patient.
I have the following XML structure.
<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:Note>Some remark text</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:Note>Charge: 1234567*</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:Note>Quantity: 1000*</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:Note>Charge: 987654*</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:Note>Quantity: 5000*</cbc:Note>
    ...
</cac:InvoiceLine>

The Charge and Quantity are connected. Charge 1234567 has a Quantity of 1000 kg.
Now I want to loop through the list and print all connected data in one (!) line like:

1000 kg Charge 1234567
5000 kg Charge 987654

I've tried the following code, but actually this code is printing a new line for each <cbc:Note> field.
<xsl:for-each select="./cbc:Note">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(.,'Charge:')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Charge:'),'*')"/>
      <br />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(.,'Menge:')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Quantity:'),'*')"/>
      <br />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <br />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>

Any ideas how to solve this?

How exactly are Charge and Quantity "connected"? Is every Charge followed immediately by its Quantity?

Yes, the lines in cbc:Note are written below each other. So first is Chargeprinted, then the connected Quantity

Which XSLT processor and/or which XSLT version do you use? In XSLT 2 or later it seems you could use <xsl:for-each-group select="cbc:Note" group-starting-with="cbc:Note[starts-with(., 'Charge:')]">

Yes, Version 2. I will try your idea. Thanks

Maybe not after all. I receive the warning: The element 'template' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' has invalid child element 'for-each-group' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'. List of possible elements expected: 'apply-templates, call-template, apply-imports, for-each, value-of, copy-of, number, choose, if, text, copy, variable, message, fallback, processing-instruction, comment, element, attribute' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' as well as any element in namespace '##other'.

Please do not post code in comments. If necessary, edit your question and add your attempt and any error message there. Note also that your question lacks a [mcve] in terms of both input (missing namespace declarations) and XSLT code.

First, that's no code, it is a warning! And it was a reaction to the code postet in 2 comments above, not to my initial question!

Makes no difference. FYI, the suggestion to use xsl:for-each-group is valid (provided your processor supports XSLT 2.0 +), though I doubt in the given case it has a real advantage over the accepted answer.

It does make a difference. I merely wrote an error message / warning in my comment. The code was 2 comments before and not from me! It can
be that xsl:for-each-group is the better solution, but it did not work in my case. As I wrote in my question, I am not an expert in XSLT and I'm just interested in a working solution to my problem.

You seem to interpret your implementation errors as problems with the suggested approach, both here and in the accepted answer. The correct approach is to add your attempt to your question (as I already stated earlier).

Try something like:
<xsl:template match="cac:InvoiceLine">
    <xsl:for-each select="cbc:Note[starts-with(., 'Charge: ')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(following-sibling::cbc:Note[1], 'Quantity: '), '*')"/>
        <xsl:text> kg </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '*')"/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


You can see it working here.

Sorry, this solution does not seem to work. No output is given.

I found this in a comment here: "For other researchers: The short answer is that preceding/following-sibling:: isn't accessible in a for-each loop because in XSLT the for-each loop isn't a loop, technically speaking. It doesn't "know" which elements are preceding and following the one currently being processed. There are other ways to accomplish something similar in a for-each loop, but that princess is in another castle." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246371/how-to-get-the-following-sibling-in-xslt

You can see my suggestion working in the link I added to my answer.

Sorry, you are completely right. It was an issue with a blank space. It works!

@dns_nx The passage you quote is correct, but you have taken it out of its (limited) context. The truth is that the current node in xsl:for-each does "know" its siblings in the source XML document.  It does not have access to other nodes in the current node list, because xsl:for-each is indeed not a loop.
